# Adding variables and static values to jQuery CSS

Tags: jquery

I have some code that looks like this:

```
$("#discription").css({'left', '500px + $(current).width();'});
```

`$(current)` is an image that is always changing. When it has a width of 50px for example, I would like 'left' to have the value of 550px.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add 500 to the current width, then concatenate the "px;"

```
$("#discription").css({'left', (500 + $(current).width()) + 'px'});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var leftWidth = 500 + $(current).width();
leftWidth += "px";
$("#discription").css({'left', leftWidth});
```